# MySQL - Master to master replication without downtime in Live production

Tags: mysql, replication, multi-master, master-master-replication

I want to setup 2 node master-master replication. Im aware of the point of failiures in this replication. Its a huge database around 1.5TB.
Heavy OLTP is going on. But its mandatory to implement right now.

I have 2 servers.

```
 1. Master1 
 2. Master2
```

Initially what I did is,

**Master1:**

- Make changes my.cnf for replication.
- Take mysqldump with --master-data=2 (For getting exact binlog
  position)

**Master2:**

- Restore dump to Master2.
- Make changes on my.cnf.
- set replication to Master1 (Change master='Master1').
- Start Slave.

> Now Master1 is replicating to Master2.

Then I need to replicate the *`Master2 to Master1`*.
Just take the binlog position and set replication on Master1 will work, but the problem is binog file and position is changing frequently.
So before execute the Change master command on Master1 the binog get changed.

How can I achive this without downtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am glad you were able to mysqldump 1.5TB database. You are sure patient.

Now for the reality check. You will some downtime for reboots and pausing.

No need to mysqldump anymore.

## STEP 01

Did you put this line in `/etc/my.cnf` on both Master1 and Master2 ?

```
log-slave-updates
```

If you not sure, run this on both Master1 and Master

```
select @@global.log_slave_updates;
```

If you get this on both Master1 and Master2

```
mysql> select @@global.log_slave_updates;
+----------------------------+
| @@global.log_slave_updates |
+----------------------------+
|                          1 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

then goto `STEP 02`.

This needs to be in `/etc/my.cnf` on both Master1 and Master2.

If you did not, please add it and restart mysqld on both Master1 and Master2.

## STEP 02

Did you enable binary logging on Master2 ?

You should have a line in Master1's `/etc/my.cnf` like this

```
log-bin = ....
```

Please make sure Master2 has it.

If you are not sure if it has it, login to MySQL on Master2 and run

```
mysql> show binary logs;
```

If it echoes

```
mysql> show binary logs;
ERROR 1381 (HY000): You are not using binary logging
```

Then, add that `log-bin` line to `/etc/my.cnf` in Master2 and restart mysql in Master2.

Once [log-slave-updates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) and [log-bin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin) have been enabled on both Master1 and Master2, you are ready to setup replication in the other direction

## STEP 03

On Master2

```
STOP SLAVE;
FLUSH TABLES;
FLUSH LOGS;
SHOW BINARY LOGS;
```

## STEP 04

On Master1

```
CHANGE MASTER TO
    MASTER_HOST='IP or Hostname of Master2',
    MASTER_PORT=3306,
    MASTER_USER='...',
    MASTER_PASSWORD='...',
    MASTER_LOG_FILE='First Binary Log On Master2',
    MASTER_LOG_POS=4
;
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
```

## STEP 05

Test Connectivity from Master1 to Master2

On Master1

```
START SLAVE IO_THREAD;
DO SLEEP(10);
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
```

Look for `Slave_IO_Running`. It should be 'Yes'.

Run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` like 3-5 times. `Relay_Log_Space` should be increasing.

## STEP 06

Start processing SQL from Relay Logs

Run this on Master1

```
START SLAVE SQL_THREAD;
DO SLEEP(10);
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
```

Look for `Slave_SQL_Running`. It should be 'Yes'.

Look for `Seconds_Behind_Master`. It should be 0. If it greater than 0, keep running `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` until `Seconds_Behind_Master` is 0.

Comment: Thanks, Is any other way to setup initial replication without mysqldump? its taking more time and resource.

Comment: Step 4 must be changed to `CHANGE MASTER` in newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm not able to comment yet I need to write a new answer. I would like to add to the 6 steps of @RolandoMySQLDBA that the `CHANGE MASTER TO` command did not work for me. As the last command of STEP 03 you should run

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
```

instead of

```
SHOW BINARY LOGS;
```

and use the respective output as `MASTER_LOG_FILE` and `MASTER_LOG_POS` in the `CHANGE MASTER TO` command of STEP 04.